# Envoy ext_authz filter before lua

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm trying to add ext_authz filter to our filter chain. Problem is that we already have LUA filter that adds some HTTP headers and our routes are based on cluster_header. As I understand they both don't work together. If I change routes' cluster_header to exact cluster - ext_auth is called, otherwise LUA filter works. Is there any way to make them work together, except of calling auth service inside LUA?

Config looks like:

```html
filter_chains:
  - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
        stat_prefix: ingress_http
        route_config:
          name: local_route
          virtual_hosts:
            - name: main
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
                - match:
                    prefix: "/"
                  route:
                    cluster_header: cluster
                    hash_policy:
                      header:
                        header_name: balancing-key
                  metadata:
                    filter_metadata:
                      envoy.lua:
                        default_cluster: some-cluster                
         http_filters:
           - name: envoy.ext_authz
             typed_config:
               "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.ext_authz.v2.ExtAuthz
               grpc_service:
                 envoy_grpc:
                   cluster_name: ext-authz
           - name: envoy.lua
             typed_config:
               "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua
               inline_code: some-code
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I've just moved ext_authz filter after lua and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Topic on github: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/8250

Last comment:

If you look at the "decode headers called" lines (which come after the filter is invoked), I believe ext_authz is being called before lua. It's just not doing anything. There is an if statement in that filter's decodeHeader implementation that skips work without logging if there's no route or cluster. Thus, if you have cluster_header: cluster into your config and use the lua filter to set the cluster header, then the ext_authz won't make an auth call.